# Python 3 Empty input if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

I have this issue that for an input I want to apply an if condition such that if the user does not enter any input, it gives a certain message and if there is an input, just thanks is displayed.
What would the code be in such a situation?

Comment: Don't be shy, show us what code you have so far. Also, you might want to check out [ask].

Comment: You should check what the input returns when nothing is typed and use that for your if statement.

Answer (score 1):

First of all welcome to Stackoverflow. But if you want help you should share your code with us. But the if/else template is :

```
if(input is empty):
          do something
else:
          print("Thanks!")
```